# passing object to for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a for loop that runs through a selection of li's via a data attribute.

I want each group of Lis to have a staggered fade in.  This works fine until I put the animation inside a `setTimeout` . Instead of looping through each li, it sticks on the number 5.

JS:

```
for (i=0;i<6;i++) {
console.log(thisI);
var thisLi = $("li[data-order='"+i+"']");

setTimeout(function() {
TweenMax.to(thisLi,0.4, {css:{opacity:1}});
},200*i);

}
```

HTMl

```
 <li data-order="1">sometext</li>
 <li data-order="1">sometext</li>
 <li data-order="2">sometext</li>
 <li data-order="3">sometext</li>
 <li data-order="2">sometext</li>
 <li data-order="3">sometext</li>
```

CSS

```
li {
    opacity:0;
}
```

Here's chromes log when I `console.log(thisLi);` inside the `setTimeout` :

`<li data-order=​"5" style=​"opacity:​ 0.11640000000000006;​ ">​…​</li>​
, 
<li data-order=​"5" style=​"opacity:​ 0.11640000000000006;​ ">​…​</li>​
]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By the time the `setTimeout` callback executes, the loop has already finished so `i` has reached it's maximum value. You can use a closure to capture the value of `i` at each iteration:

```
for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    (function (i) {
        var thisLi = $("li[data-order='" + i + "']");
        setTimeout(function () {
            TweenMax.to(thisLi, 0.4, { css: { opacity:1 } });
        }, 200 * i);
    }(i));
}
```

Side note: if you're not declaring `i` elsewhere, then it's leaking into the global scope.

Comment: @FrankAstin - What do you mean?

Comment: Stop it leaking into global space?

Comment: Oh, just declare it with `var`. You almost always should declare variables with the `var` statement. e.g. `var i = 0;`

Comment: The `i` variable I'm talking about is the one in your `for` loop. That's what's leaking into the global scope. So you need `for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++)`. The `i` inside the closure is not leaking, because it's just an argument to a function.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you have a problem with the scope of the variable thisLi. Try to create a closure like this:

```
var thisLi = $("li[data-order='"+i+"']");
var f = function() {TweenMax.to(thisLi,0.4, {css:{opacity:1}});};

setTimeout(f,i*200);
```